# Lilypond Mac OS X build issue

Tags: macos, lilypond

I am trying to do a clean build of Lilypond on a clean install of Mac OS X. Dependencies have been installed using Brew.

I do `./configure && make all` in the Lilypond dir. It gets through the configure and starts building but ends on 
`ERROR: In procedure dynamic-link:
ERROR: file: "libguile-srfi-srfi-1-v-3", message: "file not found"`

I know what libguile is, I don't know if it's on my system (or where it ought to be) but the configure script completes successfully and does not identify it as a missing dependency so I assume it was able to find it.

Any suggestions? Googling shows some old hints with regards to setting `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it seems these don't apply to Mac OS 10.6.

Answer (score 2):

There is a port of lilypond available from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

```
$ port info lilypond
lilypond @2.12.3, Revision 3 (textproc)
Variants:             [+]docs, gui, universal

Description:          Lilypond is a unix-based automated engraving system that generates beautiful sheet music from input files. Lilypond uses its
                      own input format, .ly, which in many ways is similar to LaTeX. Lilypond can export sheet music to PDF, EPS, SVG, and PNG
                      formats, and can also create MIDI files.
Homepage:             http://lilypond.org/

Library Dependencies: fontforge, ghostscript, mftrace, guile, texinfo, pango, flex, urw-fonts, netpbm
Platforms:            darwin
License:              unknown
Maintainers:          snc@macports.org, openmaintainer@macports.org
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the dynamic libraries have a .dylib extension, but need a .so extension.

I worked around this by creating links in /opt/local/lib

```
Owner-Users-MacBook-Pro-15:~ Carl$ ls -l /opt/local/lib | grep .so

-rwxr-xr-x    2 root  admin     45152 Mar 11 12:19 libXcursor.1.dylib

-rw-r--r--    2 root  admin     50232 Mar 11 12:19 libXcursor.a

lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        18 Mar 11 12:19 libXcursor.dylib -> libXcursor.1.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x    2 root  admin      1105 Mar 11 12:19 libXcursor.la

lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        32 Mar 11 21:19 libguile-srfi-srfi-1-v-3.so -> libguile-srfi-srfi-1-v-3.3.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        36 Mar 11 21:19 libguile-srfi-srfi-13-14-v-3.so -> libguile-srfi-srfi-13-14-v-3.3.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        32 Mar 11 21:20 libguile-srfi-srfi-4-v-3.so -> libguile-srfi-srfi-4-v-3.3.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        33 Mar 11 21:20 libguile-srfi-srfi-60-v-2.so -> libguile-srfi-srfi-60-v-2.2.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        17 Mar 11 21:21 libguile.so -> libguile.17.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin        30 Mar 11 21:22 libguilereadline-v-17.so -> libguilereadline-v-17.17.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Lilypond on macOS is to use [lyp](http://lyp.noteflakes.com/). Apart from installing lyp itself, which is a Ruby gem, there's no other dependency to install, no compilation step. Plus, you can install multiple versions of Lilypond and easily switch between them.

```
$ gem install lyp
$ lyp install lilypond
```

To install a specific version:

```
$ lyp install lilypond@2.19.53
```